# upload image in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How we can upload an image in web api , the image is sent from android and web application.What is the best practice. I have previously used the `httppostedfilebase` in mvc but in web api it does not seem to work.which is the best practice should i send base64 converted string from android to my web api or is there any other better way.

I have seen some examples but they are not what i am looking for.
for ex:
I don't want to use `HttpContext.Current.Request`

I need to post other form values along with image so something like this would not work

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUserImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when working with images I'll look at the whole process chain. In my example, I store it in a SQL database as a varbinary(max). I'll bring it in as a byte[] in the DAL of the API and then I have a simple utility method for converting it into a base64 string enclosed in a formatted string intended to drop directly into the src attribute of the html img tag which I can pass back to the client as a string.

That is the easiest way for me to avoid having to mess with it much. You answer is buried in that flow, if I didn't go ahead and wrap the damn thing in a formatted field for the src img tag, then yea base64 converted string is how I convert and would pass it around specifically with web api.

Comment: agree binary is the easiest way to go but does it reduces image quality and are there any chances of corruption of image data.I have these concerns thats why i want to store file on physical folder so there is no chance of data corruption.